# Make a custom helper available to both Mailer and View in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, helper, mailer

is this the best way to make a helper available to both Mailer and view in Rails 3.1?

```
class EventMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include MailerHelper
  helper :mailer
```

I tried

```
helper :mailer
```

on its own, but that didn't allow me to use the helpers in the EventMailer class.

I tried

```
add_template_helper(MailerHelper)
```

but had the same problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The rails helpers are supposed to be **view** helpers.

You will notice that the following code :

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    helper :my
end
```

will make the methods in `MyHelper` available to the views, but **not** to your controller actions. `include MyHelper` will make the helper methods available in the controller.

Summarized :

`helper :my` and you can use the helpers in your views

`include MyHelper` and you can use the helpers in your controller

I explained a bit more, but you already answered your question :

```
class EventMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    include MailerHelper
    helper :mailer

    # rest of the code goes here ...
end
```

will do what you want and allow you to use your helper in both your mailer and your views.

Hope this helps.