# I am getting a error when calling a mailer_helper method for a mailer method in a Rails 3.2.13 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416978/how-to-use-my-view-helpers-in-my-actionmailer-views) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681607/where-do-i-put-helper-methods-for-actionmailer-views) I put together the following.

In app/helpers/mailer_helper.rb:

```
module MailerHelper
  def sys_addy
    @sys_addy = current_site == "site1" ? "me@site1.com" : "me@site2.com"
  end
end
```

Attempt 1 placing the helper method call above the method - app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper :mailer
  sys_addy
  default :from => @sys_addy

  def notice_email
    ...
  end
end
```

Attempt 2 placing the helper method call inside the method - app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper :mailer

  def notice_email
    sys_addy
    ...
    mail( ...:from => @sys_addy )
  end
end
```

In both cases I got:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `sys_addy'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you wanted to use `include MailerHelper` in your UserMailer model

Comment: @MrYoshiji, using include MailerHelper is producing the same error.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795109/make-a-custom-helper-available-to-both-mailer-and-view-in-rails-3-1

Comment: @MrYoshiji, so instead of a mailer_helper file, I should put the method in a controller and then include that controller in the mailer file. Working on it but am getting the same error so far.

Comment: no no, just try with both `include MailerHelper` and right after it `helper :mailer`

Comment: @MrYoshiji, thanks. You got my a step closer. "current_site" is designated as a helper_method in my application controller which is throwing "NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_site' for #<UserMailer:..."

Comment: You can use `Thread.current[:site] = site` to store "dynamic" data accross your App. But it is not really safe, have a look at it if you are interested ;)

Comment: @MrYoshiji, thanks for the suggestion. Better that i don't create vulnerability in the app tho.

Comment: @MrYoshiji, if you put your solution that got me 'a step closer' into an answer, then I'll select your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include MailerHelper
  helper :mailer
```

But the problem with this solution is that the Helper can't know the result of `current_site` (I guess it is stocked in the User's session?).

A workaround is to use `Thread.current` in order to store data dynamically (can be updated):

```
Thread.current[:site] = site
```

This solution is not that safe, make sure to secure the access to this variable and also never put user's input in the `Thread.current`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are trying to define it as a symbol. Try calling it like Class like below in your `User Mailer`:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   include MailerHelper
   helper :mailer       

  def notice_email
    sys_addy
    ...
    mail( ...:from => @sys_addy )
  end
end
```

Update : use both (include & helper) or try with below :

```
add_template_helper(MailerHelper)
```

This way, you can access this method in your views as well. 
Hope, it will help.Thanks

Comment: I tried "helper MailerHelper" instead of "helper :mailer" and it produced "NameError (undefined local variable or method `sys_addy' for #<UserMailer:0x007fc577918478>)". Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: your answer is a summary of the solution MrYoshiji's gave me in comments that got me a step closer. In fairness to him, if he puts his solution into an answer within the next few days I will select his answer as the solution. If I don't hear from him, I'll select yours. I did upvote each of your responses tho. Thanks for your help.